# Trying to append items to a list in python but its acting odd

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have events, people can belong an event. So I have an event class that looks like:

```
class Event():
    name = ""
    people = []
```

I also have a global variable to hold all the events

```
events   = []
```

Now I'm trying to process my raw data into events and people going to them:

```
    # If there are missions, add the events
    for m in wiki.missions:
        foundEvent = False
        for e in events:
            if e.name == m:
                foundEvent = True
                foundPerson = False
                for p in e.people:
                    if p.rawName == person.rawName:
                        foundPerson = True
                if not foundPerson:
                    e.people.append(person)
                    print "Added " + person.display + " to " + m + " (" + str(len(e.people)) + ")"

        if foundEvent == False:
            event = Event()
            event.name = m
            event.people.append(person)
            print "New " + person.display + " to " + m + " (" + str(len(event.people)) + ")"
            events.append(event)
            event = None
```

Based on my print statements I can see who is added to existing event and when and who makes a new event. The odd thing is the count of people in an event is always increments the people in all events.

```
New Joseph M. Acaba to STS-119 (1)
New Joseph M. Acaba to Soyuz TMA-04M (2)
New Joseph M. Acaba to Expedition 31 Expedition 32 (3)
Added Dominic A. Antonelli to STS-119 (4)
New Dominic A. Antonelli to STS-132 (5)
Added Richard R. Arnold to STS-119 (6)
```

This makes no sense to me, what is it than I am doing wrong? (I'm sure there is a lot)

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.. Can you also show the expected output?? And what you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using instance variables instead of class variables. So set up your class something like this, and modify the rest of your code to fit it:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.people = []
```

The important difference here is just as you described: instance variables are set for a specific instance of the class, whereas class variables are set for *all* instances of that class.

Comment: I have to wonder... how the heck to any of my classes work at all :-/ Pure luck I suppose :)

Comment: @Justin808 When you assign e.g. `event.name = m` you create a new instance variable that shadows the class variable. `event.people.append()` is a different case: it mutates the class variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating class variables, not instance variables, therefore you keep appending people to the class instead of each new object you're creating.

Try this instead:

```
class Event():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = ""
        self.people = []
```

and later

```
event = Event(m)
event.people.append(person)
```